# Hide icons status bar MIUI 13

Tags: android-12, xiaomi, miui

I am trying to hide some status bar icons on MIUI 13.

Do you know of a way to hide icons such as Roaming, Mute, DND...?

[image]

I tried these without success:

- `adb shell settings put secure icon_blacklist zen,mute,volume`
- Using the SystemUI Tuner app, grating all permissions.
- Using the Activity Launcher and opening the System UI demo mode.
- ADB AppControl

Answer (score 1):

Old question but I faced the same issue so here is how I fixed it.

0. First you must have the Developer status enabled.
1. Then enable the following settings in the Developer options:

   USB debugging

   Wireless debugging

   USB debugging (Security settings)
2. Restart phone and connect it to your computer where `ABD` is downloaded
3. Open terminal where `ADB` is unzipped
4. Do the following commands:

   ```
    ./adb devices
   ```

   This should list the device and show it connected

   ```
   ./adb shell settings put secure icon_blacklist nfc,zen,volume
   ```

   This will hide, respectively, the nfc icon, the dnd moon crescent icon and the muted bell icon

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer. I might try again, but this is exactly what I did, and it didn't work for me, don't know why. I saw you added nfc, I wonder if there is one for the roaming icon too.

Comment: If you get a requires:android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS error, you need to enable the second USB debugging. It requires you to sign in to your Xiaomi account in the settings.

Answer (score 0):

I just went through the same on a POCO X5 5G and got the "requires:android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" error.

Went looking for that "second USB debugging" that @peterkodermac mentioned and found it labelled "OEM unlocking".

The command

adb shell settings put secure icon_blacklist nfc

then worked well.
No need to have the "zen" and "volume" things there... I'm not sure they do anything.

Don't forget to re-enable OEM unlocking after this. The phone will say that it needs to reboot in order to enable it again... fine!